# How to resolve unable to acquire singleton lock issue in Azure WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I am getting unable to acquire singleton lock issue when I am running the application locally. How may I resolve it?

Below is my code

```
static void Main()
    {
        JobHostConfiguration config = new`enter code here` JobHostConfiguration();
        config.UseTimers();
        AutoMapperManager.SetAutomapper();
        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);

        //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("GetActionItemPullData")));
        config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Regards,
Vantage

Comment: are you using the same storage account on another webjob ?

Comment: Yes, the same storage

Comment: I have a similar issue with two webjobs that used both timetrigger. I think they have to use different storage accounts because the lock is at the storage level so when the first job acquires the singleton lock, the second job cannot acquire the same lock or something like that. can you try to use two different storage accounts ?

Comment: Do you happen to get a blob id or lock id that it can't acquire?  If so, you should be able to find that blob in your storage account /azure-webjobs-hosts/locks/<guid>/<lockid>.  You can try deleting it ... I've not tried that before but if you can remove the blob and restart your webjob locally it might work.  If you share the storage account with a job running in azure you will be tripping over it with the locks. Two choices that I know of: 1. use a different storage account 2. (total hack but should work) rename the function while debugging so the lock listener blob name will be different.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer.

Comment: I encountered a similar error message and it appears to disable my blob triggers.  There are a bunch of open bugs in various Azure functions projects that look related.  Some have been open for years.  I just started cross-linking a few of them, but you can start here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/822.  I haven't discovered any actual solutions yet.

Comment: @JasonHaley how do we specify one storage account for local run and another storage account for the cloud run?

Answer (score 4):

You can overwrite the host ID to something other than the default.
This code snippet is for v3 of the WebJobs SDK, but there is a similar setting also for the v2. This solution even works, if multiple people work locally on the same project.

```
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(context =>
{
  if (IsLocal)
  {
    context.UseHostId(Environment.UserName);
  }

  // other context operations
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me that I migrated the web jobs to a new app service and I was getting the same error. After looking at everything I figured out what it was:

Make sure no instance of the web job is running in Azure. That means, stop the web job in Azure. Even the local copy won't run if you are targeting the same storage account.

**Stopping the app service doesn't stop the web jobs. You need to stop the web jobs explicitly.**

Adding a verbose logging level helped me a lot.

```
config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Verbose;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have published your webjob already to Azure, make sure it is not running there when in the meantime trying to run it locally.

Answer (score 2):

```
This is the better approach I found, just sharing with you =).

    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    private static void DebugWebService(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseHostId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    }
```

Edited to adjust as Zach suggested.

Comment: Don't need to call replace just use .ToString("N") instead